# pulling data from multiple tables on the same page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck on this code and can't figure out where I need to go. I'm trying to pull name, phone number and email from table "contacts" which is dispayed on page and on the same page post notes to table "contactnotes" and then display them under the textbox. I can't figure out how to do it all on the same page. Here is what I have thus far.

```
 <?php
 mysql_connect ("link","db","pw") or die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db ("db");

 $ID = $_GET['ID'];
 $notes = $_POST['notes'];

 $query="INSERT INTO contactnotes (id, notes)VALUES ('NULL', '".$notes."')";

 mysql_query($query) or die ('Error Updating Database');


 $sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE ID='$ID' limit 1" or die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error: ' .mysql_error());

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 ?>

 <!-- CONTACT INFO -->
 <div id="contact-table"><?php include("contact-info.php"); ?></div>
 <br />
 <form method="post" action="/db/notes.php?ID=<? echo $row['ID']; ?>"/>
 <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>" name = "id" id="id"/>  
 <br />

 <input type="submit" value="Edit Contact">
 <input type="submit" value="Delete Contact">
 <br />
 <br />
 <hr />
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td><strong>Notes</strong></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>  
 <td><textarea name="notes" id="notes" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <br />
 <hr/>
 <br />
 <table width="950" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
 <tr>
 <td align="left" width="100%"><h5><strong><? echo $row['user']; ?> on <? echo date("F d Y @ h:i:s", strtotime($row['timestamp'])); ?> wrote:</strong></h5></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <br />
 <td align="left" width="100%"><? echo $row['notes']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <hr/>
 <br />
 <input type="submit" value="Edit Contact">
 <input type="submit" value="Delete Contact">
 </form>
 <?
 mysql_close();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [MySQL JOIN](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php).

Comment: Thank you, I've read that several times and still am having difficulty. I'm just learning JOIN so any additional help would be great.

Comment: JOINS allow you to connect two tables based on a common field. Say you have a user id in both tables you would `SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.user_id` or something similar.

Comment: this is one of the confusing areas for me. On both tables I have an ID that is auto inc. and in addition on table2 I have a user_id that doesn't auto inc. Which do I use? When you say a common field, I don't know what would be common. So, if I had Table1=lead (ID,name,phone,timestamp) Table2=notes (ID,user_id,notes,timestamp) would I do `SELECT * FROM lead JOIN notes on lead.id = notes.user_id` ?